# Get data from multiple rows

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I would like to get the value of the column `uid` from **all** rows where the value of the column `city` is `london`.

I have tried it like this:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Personal::class)->findOneBy(['city' => 'london']);
```

but then I get an object from only 1 row. What I need is simply an array that looks kind of like this:

> array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **findBy** instead *findOneBy*. It gives you array of entities.

But you can`t define, which column should be fetched. 
For that you should use DQL where you define what should be fetched.

For example with query builder:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('p.uid')
    ->from(Personal::class, 'p')
    ->where('p.city = \'london\'');

$uids = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [findBy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Personal::class)->findBy(['city' => 'london']);
```

findOneBy method return only one row

See [Simple Conditions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

Comment: Good to know about that. Thank you!